# A count variable function in R

Tags: r, if-statement, count

I am trying to create a new index variable from 0-100% from multiple survey items (q1:q15) with a 7pt. response scale. I found an example in Excel that will accomplish this using the Count function but I would like to automate this with R. There are missing data for some of the items.

I also need to specify the following criteria: At least one item from each of the following groups of items (q1:q3,q4:q6,q7:q9, q10:q12) must have data or the Index should result in NA.

```
structure(list(q1 = c(6L, 5L, 2L, 7L), q2 = c(5L, 5L, 6L, 7L), 
q3 = c(4L, NA, 2L, 7L), q4 = c(NA, 5L, 5L, 5L), q5 = c(NA, 
6L, 6L, 6L), q6 = c(NA, 6L, 2L, 7L), q7 = c(6L, 7L, 7L, 7L
), q8 = c(5L, 6L, NA, 7L), q9 = c(6L, 5L, 7L, 7L), q10 = c(7L, 
NA, 5L, 7L), q11 = c(6L, 5L, 7L, 7L), q12 = c(6L, 6L, 2L, 
7L), q13 = c(6L, 5L, 6L, 7L), q14 = c(4L, 4L, 1L, 7L), q15 = c(6L, 
7L, 4L, 7L)), .Names = c("q1", "q2", "q3", "q4", "q5", "q6", 
"q7", "q8", "q9", "q10", "q11", "q12", "q13", "q14", "q15"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

The coding works in Excel (except for the criteria about non-missing data in the groups of items):

```
=(SUM(q1:q15)-COUNT(q1:q15))/((COUNT(q1:q15)*7)-COUNT(q1:q15))*100
```

Thanks for assistance.

The calculation for the Index above is [the sum for items q1:q15 minus the minimum possible sum (since my scale is 1-7 this would be the number of non-missing items * 1)] divided by [the maximum possible sum (on a scale of 1-7 the number of non-missing items * 7) - the minimum possible sum]. The output I'm trying to generate adds a new variable "Index" with a value in that colum for each row:

```
structure(list(q1 = c(6L, 5L, 2L, 7L), q2 = c(5L, 5L, 6L, 7L), 
q3 = c(4L, NA, 2L, 7L), q4 = c(NA, 5L, 5L, 5L), q5 = c(NA, 
6L, 6L, 6L), q6 = c(NA, 6L, 2L, 7L), q7 = c(6L, 7L, 7L, 7L 
), q8 = c(5L, 6L, NA, 7L), q9 = c(6L, 5L, 7L, 7L), q10 = c(7L, 
NA, 5L, 7L), q11 = c(6L, 5L, 7L, 7L), q12 = c(6L, 6L, 2L, 
7L), q13 = c(6L, 5L, 6L, 7L), q14 = c(4L, 4L, 1L, 7L), q15 = c(6L, 
7L, 4L, 7L), Index = c(NA, 75.64102564, 57.14285714, 96.66666667 
)), .Names = c("q1", "q2", "q3", "q4", "q5", "q6", "q7", 
"q8", "q9", "q10", "q11", "q12", "q13", "q14", "q15", "Index" 
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Please share your expected output for this example dataset.

Comment: Is `COUNT(q1:q15)*7)-COUNT(q1:q15)` ever different from `COUNT(q1:q15)*6`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

Let's define a function to work on a single row. 
I first check the inputs by putting the row into a 3-row matrix and summing the NA values in each column. If any of the columns have 3 missing values, we return `NA` as per your input check.

Then I attempted to simplify your formula. I believe `SUM(q1:q15)-COUNT(q1:q15)` can be simplified to `sum(x - 1)` and  `COUNT(q1:q15)*7-COUNT(q1:q15)` is `COUNT(q1:q15)*6` is `sum((!is.na(x)) * 6)`.

```
f = function(x) {
    if (any(colSums(matrix(is.na(x), nrow = 3)) == 3)) return(NA)
    sum(x - 1, na.rm = T) / sum((!is.na(x)) * 6) * 100
}
apply(df, 1, f)
# [1] NA 75.64103 57.14286 96.66667
```

**Edit**

To add this to the original data as a column, just assign it:

```
res = df
res$Index = apply(df, 1, f)
res
#   q1 q2 q3 q4 q5 q6 q7 q8 q9 q10 q11 q12 q13 q14 q15    Index
# 1  6  5  4 NA NA NA  6  5  6   7   6   6   6   4   6       NA
# 2  5  5 NA  5  6  6  7  6  5  NA   5   6   5   4   7 75.64103
# 3  2  6  2  5  6  2  7 NA  7   5   7   2   6   1   4 57.14286
# 4  7  7  7  5  6  7  7  7  7   7   7   7   7   7   7 96.66667
```

---

Thinking about this a little more, it's like your taking an average of `(x - 1) / 6` and then multiplying by 100. The following function is even simpler and yields the same result:

```
f2 = function(x) {
    if (any(colSums(matrix(is.na(x), nrow = 3)) == 3)) return(NA)
    mean((x - 1) / 6, na.rm = T) * 100
}

res$Index = apply(df, 1, f2)
```

**Edit:** This average is a much nicer way to put your very round-about description:

> The calculation for the Index above is [the sum for items q1:q15 minus the minimum possible sum (since my scale is 1-7 this would be the number of non-missing items * 1)] divided by [the maximum possible sum (on a scale of 1-7 the number of non-missing items * 7) - the minimum possible sum]. The output I'm trying to generate adds a new variable "Index" with a value in that colum for each row:

So basically, you are scoring things from 1-7 and you want the average percent correct. First we subtract off 1 to make the scores 0-6 (because 0 is a nicer minimum than 1), then we divide by 6 to make the scores decimal between 0-1, and then we average, ignoring missing values of course. Multiply by 100 to convert to percentage. This is the code above:

```
mean((x - 1) / 6, na.rm = T) * 100
```

Comment: Thank you for response. I'm not sure that I understand the reproducible output you provided. I've updated my question to include some explanation behind the Index calculation and the desired output in the dataframe with the new variable "Index." When I ran f2 the output for the Index was 96.66667, which appears to match row 4 of the desired output I posted. Given my update, would you be able to demonstrate the coding to obtain output in the format I posted? Many thanks.

Comment: Sorry! I was working on two questions at once and the `dput` I shared at the bottom belongs to the other question.

Comment: I had also missed a couple parens in `f` - now both `f` and `f2` are working, and I added code to assign the result to a column.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(expss)
dfs = structure(list(q1 = c(6L, 5L, 2L, 7L), q2 = c(5L, 5L, 6L, 7L),
               q3 = c(4L, NA, 2L, 7L), q4 = c(NA, 5L, 5L, 5L),
               q5 = c(NA, 6L, 6L, 6L), q6 = c(NA, 6L, 2L, 7L),
               q7 = c(6L, 7L, 7L, 7L), q8 = c(5L, 6L, NA, 7L), q9 = c(6L, 5L, 7L, 7L),
               q10 = c(7L, NA, 5L, 7L), q11 = c(6L, 5L, 7L, 7L), q12 = c(6L, 6L, 2L,  7L),
               q13 = c(6L, 5L, 6L, 7L), q14 = c(4L, 4L, 1L, 7L),
               q15 = c(6L,7L, 4L, 7L)), .Names = c("q1", "q2", "q3", "q4", "q5", "q6",  "q7", "q8", "q9", "q10", "q11", "q12", "q13", "q14", "q15"),
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,   -4L))


dfs$Index = with(dfs,{
                  gr1 = count_row_if(not_na, q1, q2, q3)>0
                  gr2 = count_row_if(not_na, q4, q5, q6)>0
                  gr3 = count_row_if(not_na, q7, q8, q9)>0
                  gr4 = count_row_if(not_na, q10, q11, q12)>0
                  ifelse(gr1 & gr2 & gr3 & gr4,
                     (sum_row(q1 %to% q15)- count_row_if(not_na, q1  %to% q15))/(count_row_if(not_na, q1  %to% q15)*6)*100,
                        NA
                  )
})

dfs
```